# What component can be used to duplicate every row of an excel file using Talend?

Tags: talend, talend-mdm

If I have an excel file with rows like this:

```
val1 | val2 | val3 | val4
val5 | val6 | val7 | val8
```

then I need the result to be this:

```
val1 | val2 | val3 | val4
val1 | val2 | val3 | val4
val5 | val6 | val7 | val8
val5 | val6 | val7 | val8
```

Is this possible with Talend?

EDIT: Notice the order of the rows. I need them to maintain order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send 2 identical inputs to a tUnite to duplicate the row. Then send the rows to a tSort to sort them.

[image]

The 2 tFlowInput are identical, replace them with what you have.

[image]

Sync Columns on the tJoin.
Set the columns to sort on the tSort

[image]

Output :

```
.---------+----------+----------+----------.
|                tLogRow_1                 |
|=--------+----------+----------+---------=|
|newColumn|newColumn1|newColumn2|newColumn3|
|=--------+----------+----------+---------=|
|val1     |val2      |val3      |val3      |
|val1     |val2      |val3      |val3      |
|val5     |val6      |val7      |val8      |
|val5     |val6      |val7      |val8      |
'---------+----------+----------+----------'
```

Comment: Depending on the size of the initial file, reading it twice could be quite heavy. Same if they are a lot of columns and you have to sort by each. That said if it's no problem, it is indeed simpler to do it that way.

Comment: Do I have to type out all of the columns manually like you do in your second step? @RealHowTo

Comment: Because my input is a tFileInputExcel

Comment: @mastercool, yes you have to do it at least one time. Make a schema (metadata/generic schema) then you will be able to reuse it in all your component by selecting `schema>Repository>Generic>@your_schema@`

Comment: dang, unfortunately I have over 100 rows and 20 columns. That would take a very long time

Comment: @mastercool, when you defined a schema, you only give the column names, If you create a File Excel schema, Talend can extract the column name for you.

Comment: Oh gotcha. But then I still manually have to type in the values for each row right?

Comment: No. In your tFileInputExcel, you specify ` schema>Repository>` (Generic or File Excel) schema  that you have previously defined and  you give the excel filename that you want to processed. At the execution, the data read from the file will be mapped to the right column.

Comment: Haven't tried it yet, but this sounds like it should work for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For a pure duplication, the easiest would be to use a tHashInput to store the values coming from your Excel file.

Then you can read from a linked tHashOutput twice and join the flows with a tUnite.

---

If you need to keep the order, you can add a tJavaRow or a tMap before the tHashInput to add a column "order" valued with a sequence.
Then you can add a tSortRow after the tUnite and order with the new column.
Finally, you delete the extra column with a tFilterColumn (or any other component).

[image]

Result :

[image]

Code for the order :

```
Numeric.sequence("s1",1,1);
```

Note : you might have to add the components tHashOutput and tHashInput to your palette as they are not included by default.

Comment: this will give me the desired output of each copied row is right after the row it was copied from?

Comment: @Mastercool, no, it will copy the second part after the first. Is keeping the order a requirement (it's possible but just a bit more involved) ?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it is.

Comment: I am actually a little confused, I am fairly new to Talend. Do you think you could provide the component structure so I can see it visually?